# I've created a node app through cloud 9, but how do I connect my app with my website?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, web-deployment, cloud9

I've made a Node.js app, and it functions on Cloud 9 as an HTML page, but I want to move it to a web address that I currently own and for the life of me I can't seem to figure out how to link the backend to the front end. I'm going to try to deploy the backend to a Heroku server, but how would I go about getting my app to display on a web address that I currently own?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cloud9 does not allow for public hosting of websites: [see here](https://community.c9.io/t/can-i-use-cloud9-for-hosting/16/2). You cannot point your own domain name to a cloud9 workspace.

If you're already moving a part of your app to Heroku, why not move the rest of it? Heroku provides hosting services, and you can point your domain there. See [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-domains) for a tutorial on how to do that.

Otherwise, if you have two separate apps, you can point your domain to the Heroku app, and then set up a redirect on the route/subdomain to take the user to the cloud9 app. This is bad practice, but it works.

Comment: I have a URL that I am hosting through Siteground currently and I would like to be able to host through them if possible. Any suggestions?

Comment: Host through Siteground? They seem to only support static sites. What you need is a [virtual private server](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_private_server) which Heroku provides. Set up your Heroku app, deploy, and then change the DNS records with your domain registrar to point to Heroku. Where did you buy the domain from?

Comment: Thanks for your help!

Comment: I bought it from Siteground I believe.

Comment: Ah I didn't know they provided registry services. Ok I just dug a little deeper; it seems they also offer [VPS hosting](https://www.siteground.com/cloud-hosting.htm), although it's way more expensive and unnecessarily powerful than others. If you'd like, you can transfer the domain away from Siteground to something like Google Domains or GoDaddy, which makes managing your Heroku deployment a lot easier, as those two are dedicated domain registrars/managers. Hope this helps!